# table, line with overhang

Tags: tables

The first cell in the first column should be divided by an oblique line. This line extends to the left above beyond the edge of the table. Does anyone have a solution to make the line flush with the table edge?

This is my Code:

```
documentclass[
BCOR=5mm,      
DIV=10,            
fontsize=11pt,    
oneside,            
parskip,            
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc,    
fleqn,        
numbers=noenddot        
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,includeheadfoot,headheight=18.25pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, makecell, cellspace, bigstrut}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|cccc@{}}
\backslashbox[20mm]{\textbf{Ausführung}}{\textbf{Kriterium}} &  \textbf{Akustik} & \textbf{Kosten} & \textbf{Montagefreundlichkeit} & \textbf{Wartung}\\
  \hline
  Wälzführung      & - & + & + & o \\
  Gleitführung   & + & + & + & ++ \\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Vor- und Nachteile verschiedener Führungen]{Vor- und Nachteile verschiedener Führungen \\ ++ = sehr gut, + = gut, o = ausreichend, - = unbefriedigend}
 \label{tab_fuehrungen}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

I would do your table without a slashbox, but with one more row, and a `threeparttable environment`, somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass[
BCOR=5mm,
DIV=10,
fontsize=11pt,
oneside,
parskip,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc,
fleqn,
numbers=noenddot
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,includeheadfoot,headheight=18.25pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, makecell, cellspace, bigstrut, threeparttable, boldline}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lV{3}*{4}{>{$}c<{$}}ccc@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Kriterium}} \\
      \textbf{Ausführung} & \textbf{Akustik} & \textbf{Kosten} & \textbf{Montagefreundlichkeit} & \textbf{Wartung} \\
      \hline
      Wälzführung & - & + & + & ∘ \bigstrut \\
      Gleitführung & + & + & + & ++ \\[1ex]
    \end{tabular}\smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[online, para]\footnotesize
      \item[$+$] = sehr gut,
      \item[$++$] = gut,
      \item[$\circ$] = ausreichend,
      \item[$-$] = unbefriedigend
    \end{tablenotes}
    \caption{Vor- und Nachteile verschiedener Führungen}
    \label{tab_fuehrungen}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: far better ... (+1)

Answer (score 0):

with dirty trick (since `\backslashbox` always consider `\tabcolsep`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[
BCOR=5mm,
DIV=10,
fontsize=11pt,
oneside,
parskip,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc,
fleqn,
numbers=noenddot
]{scrbook}

%\usepackage{scrhack}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,
            plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,
            footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,
            includeheadfoot,headheight=18.25pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, makecell, cellspace, bigstrut}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\extracolsep{6pt}}|cccc}
\backslashbox[12mm]{\textbf{Ausführung}}{\textbf{Kriterium}\hspace*{6pt}} &  \textbf{Akustik} & \textbf{Kosten} & \textbf{Montagefreundlichkeit} & \textbf{Wartung}\\
  \hline
  Wälzführung      & - & + & + & o \\
  Gleitführung   & + & + & + & ++ \\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Vor- und Nachteile verschiedener Führungen]{Vor- und Nachteile verschiedener Führungen \\ ++ = sehr gut, + = gut, o = ausreichend, - = unbefriedigend}
 \label{tab_fuehrungen}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`slashbox` package has been superseded by [the `diagbox` package](http://ctan.asis.io/macros/latex/contrib/diagbox/diagbox.pdf). Just use `\diagbox[outerleftsep=0pt]{..}{..}` in your case. The `outerleftsep=0pt` part is because you added `@{}` before the first column.

```
\documentclass[
BCOR=5mm,      
DIV=10,            
fontsize=11pt,    
oneside,            
parskip,            
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc,    
fleqn,        
numbers=noenddot        
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,includeheadfoot,headheight=18.25pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, makecell, cellspace, bigstrut}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|cccc@{}}
\diagbox[outerleftsep=0pt]{\textbf{Ausführung}}{\textbf{Kriterium}} &  \textbf{Akustik} & \textbf{Kosten} & \textbf{Montagefreundlichkeit} & \textbf{Wartung}\\
  \hline
  Wälzführung      & - & + & + & o \\
  Gleitführung   & + & + & + & ++ \\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Vor- und Nachteile verschiedener Führungen]{Vor- und Nachteile verschiedener Führungen \\ ++ = sehr gut, + = gut, o = ausreichend, - = unbefriedigend}
 \label{tab_fuehrungen}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]